# dalvikm threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception

Tags: java, android, uncaught-exception

I am very new to android app development. i created an app combining GCM and Webview. Actually I copied the codes and altered for my needs. App is working fine in 2.3 Gb. In  4 & above, App is stopping unexpectedly. Only for the first time. Very First time it happens. Next time onwards its working fine.

Apps activity flow is like this activity1->activity2->activity3.

Activty2(MainActivity) will be skipped when launching for the 2nd time onwards.

Here is the Error From logcat

```
    10-14 21:54:01.623: V/GCMBaseIntentService(28919): Releasing wakelock
    10-14 21:54:01.623: W/dalvikvm(28919): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41fde2a0)
    10-14 21:54:01.633: E/AndroidRuntime(28919): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[GCMIntentService-xxxxxxxx-1]
    10-14 21:54:01.633: E/AndroidRuntime(28919): java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
    10-14 21:54:01.633: E/AndroidRuntime(28919):    at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
    10-14 21:54:01.633: E/AndroidRuntime(28919):    at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:155)
    10-14 21:54:01.633: E/AndroidRuntime(28919):    at com.wCityDrugs.GCMIntentService.onRegistered(GCMIntentService.java:29)
    10-14 21:54:01.633: E/AndroidRuntime(28919):    at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService.handleRegistration(GCMBaseIntentService.java:296)
    10-14 21:54:01.633: E/AndroidRuntime(28919):    at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService.onHandleIntent(GCMBaseIntentService.java:197)
    10-14 21:54:01.633: E/AndroidRuntime(28919):    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
    10-14 21:54:01.633: E/AndroidRuntime(28919):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    10-14 21:54:01.633: E/AndroidRuntime(28919):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    10-14 21:54:01.633: E/AndroidRuntime(28919):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
    10-14 21:54:10.678: V/GCMRegistrar(28919): Unregistering receiver
    10-14 21:54:10.683: E/UnRegister Receiver Error(28919): > Receiver not registered: com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver@42e88d70
```

Here is GCMIntentService.java

```
    package com.wCityDrugs;

    import static com.wCityDrugs.CommonUtilities.SENDER_ID;
    import static com.wCityDrugs.CommonUtilities.displayMessage;
    import android.app.Notification;
    import android.app.NotificationManager;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.util.Log;

    import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;

    public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

public GCMIntentService() {
    super(SENDER_ID);
}

/**
 * Method called on device registered
 **/
@Override
protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
    displayMessage(context, "Your device registred with GCM");
    Log.d("NAME", MainActivity.name);
    ServerUtilities.register(context, MainActivity.name, MainActivity.email, registrationId);
}

/**
 * Method called on device un registred
 * */
@Override
protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Device unregistered");
    displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_unregistered));
    ServerUtilities.unregister(context, registrationId);
}

/**
 * Method called on Receiving a new message
 * */
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
    String message = intent.getExtras().getString("price");

    displayMessage(context, message);
    // notifies user
    generateNotification(context, message);
}

/**
 * Method called on receiving a deleted message
 * */
@Override
protected void onDeletedMessages(Context context, int total) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received deleted messages notification");
    String message = getString(R.string.gcm_deleted, total);
    displayMessage(context, message);
    // notifies user
    generateNotification(context, message);
}

/**
 * Method called on Error
 * */
@Override
public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
    displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_error, errorId));
}

@Override
protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
    // log message
    Log.i(TAG, "Received recoverable error: " + errorId);
    displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_recoverable_error,
            errorId));
    return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
}

/**
 * Issues a notification to inform the user that server has sent a message.
 */
private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    // set intent so it does not start a new activity
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    // Play default notification sound
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    //notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "your_sound_file_name.mp3");

    // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);      

}

}
```

And Here is my MainActivity.java

```
    package com.wCityDrugs;

    import static com.wCityDrugs.CommonUtilities.DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION;
    import static com.wCityDrugs.CommonUtilities.EXTRA_MESSAGE;
    import static com.wCityDrugs.CommonUtilities.SENDER_ID;


    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.IntentFilter;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    import android.util.Log;

    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;


    import com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {



        // label to display gcm messages
        TextView lblMessage;

        // Asyntask
        AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> mRegisterTask;

        // Alert dialog manager
        AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

        // Connection detector
        ConnectionDetector cd;



        public static String name;
        public static String email;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("ActivityPREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            if(pref.getBoolean("activity_executed", false)){
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, web_index.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } else {
                Editor ed = pref.edit();
                ed.putBoolean("activity_executed", true);
                ed.commit();
            }

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

            // Check if Internet present
            if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
                // Internet Connection is not present
                alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this,
                        "Internet Connection Error",
                        "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
                // stop executing code by return
                return;
            }

            // Getting name, email from intent
            Intent i = getIntent();

            name = i.getStringExtra("name");
            email = i.getStringExtra("email");      

            // Make sure the device has the proper dependencies.
            GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);

            // Make sure the manifest was properly set - comment out this line
            // while developing the app, then uncomment it when it's ready.
            GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

            lblMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblMessage);

            registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                    DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));

            // Get GCM registration id
            final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);

            // Check if regid already presents
            if (regId.equals("")) {
                // Registration is not present, register now with GCM           
                GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
            } else {
                // Device is already registered on GCM
                if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(this)) {
                    // Skips registration.              
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Welcome Back", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    // Try to register again, but not in the UI thread.
                    // It's also necessary to cancel the thread onDestroy(),
                    // hence the use of AsyncTask instead of a raw thread.
                    final Context context = this;
                    mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                        @Override
                        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                            // Register on our server
                            // On server creates a new user
                            ServerUtilities.register(context, name, email, regId);
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                            mRegisterTask = null;
                        }

                    };
                    mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);
                }
            }
        }       

        /**
         * Receiving push messages
         * */
        private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
                // Waking up mobile if it is sleeping
                WakeLocker.acquire(getApplicationContext());

                /**
                 * Take appropriate action on this message
                 * depending upon your app requirement
                 * For now i am just displaying it on the screen
                 * */

                // Showing received message
                lblMessage.append(newMessage + "\n");           
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New Message: " + newMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                // Releasing wake lock
                WakeLocker.release();
            }
        };

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            if (mRegisterTask != null) {
                mRegisterTask.cancel(true);
            }
            try {
                unregisterReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver);
                GCMRegistrar.onDestroy(this);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("UnRegister Receiver Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
            }
            super.onDestroy();





    }}
```

Can anyone guide me to get rid this error.

Comment: `Log.d("NAME", MainActivity.name);`  causing issue make sure `MainActivity.name` is not empty or use `Log.d("NAME"," "+ MainActivity.name);`

Comment: Brilliant........... Thanks a ton. I was scratching my head for more than a week. Thanks a lot

Comment: Thank You so much  ρяσѕρєя . Really i feel very happy